# Se me bloquea pantalla al abrir un modal de bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Hola mi problema es que se me bloquea la pantalla al abrir un modal, aparece un fondo oscuro, lo raro es que el mismo procedimiento lo he hecho en proyectos anteriores y con exito.
ESTE ES MI MODAL, ESTE ES MI CODIGO COMPLETO HTML, LA CUAL PINTO PRIMERO MI ABLA CON SUS FILTROS POR FECHA Y LUEGO UN DIV CON SU MODAL LA CUAL SE ME BLOQUEA AL LOGRAR ABRIRLO A TRAVES DE JAVASCRIPT, necesito ayuda con este problema, me parece raro el bloqueo.

```
  <section class="section-container">
     <!-- Page content-->
     <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-heading">
      <div>Órdenes</div>
    </div><!-- START card-->

       <div class="row">

                       <div class="col-md-4">
                               <h6 style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 
            30px;">Desde: </h6>
                               <div class="col-xl-8 col-10">
                                  <div class="input-group date" 
                id="datetimepicker1">
                                     <input class="form-control" 
                                    id="fecha1" 
             type="date" value="<?= $fecha1 ?>" >
                                     <span class="input-group-append 
                      <input- 
                     group-addon">
                                      <span class="input-group-text fa 
                                      fa- 
                     calendar"></span>
                                     </span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                      <h6 style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 
              30px;">Hasta: </h6>
                         <div class="col-xl-8 col-10">
                                  <div class="input-group date" 
          id="datetimepicker2">
                                     <input class="form-control" id="fecha2" 
       type="date" value="<?= $fecha2 ?>" >
                                     <span class="input-group-append input- 
                  group-addon">
                                        <span class="input-group-text fa fa- 
                  calendar"></span>
                                     </span>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">

                         <button type="button" onclick="filtrar()" class="btn 
    btn-dark" style="margin-top: 27px">
                         <i class="fa fa-search"></i>BUSCAR</button>
                      </div> 
    </div>

   <br>

  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- START card-->
        <div class="card card-default">
           <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                       <table id="Data-ordenes" class="table table-striped 
        table-bordered table-hover">
                          <thead>
                             <tr>
                                <th>Incio traslado</th>
                                <th>Fin traslado</th>
                                <th>Motivo</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Unidad</th>
                                <th>Id Destinatario</th>
                                <th>Nombre Destinatario</th>
                                <th>destino</th>
                                <th>Chofer</th>
                                <th>CI Chofer</th> 
                                <th>Nombre camión</th>
                                <th>Placa</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>

                             </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody id="ordenes-completado">

                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div><!-- END card-->
     </div>
  </div><!-- END row-->
  <!-- START card-->
   </div>
 </section><!-- Page footer-->
      <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" >
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">        
      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Guardar</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
       </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

ABRO EL MODAL CON LA SIGUIENTE LINEA DE CODIGO A TRAVES DE JAVASCRIPT

```
        $("#myModal").modal();
```

[image: No obtengo errores de consola]

[image: Este error es el que aparece al abrir cualquier modal]

Comment: El div de la clase "modal-content" no esta cerrado. Agrega información si hay en la consola.

Comment: Si está cerrado el div

Comment: La imagen de tu modal no se corresponde con el html que publicas. Y no veo código javascript que cargue el contenido del modal de manera asíncrona. Yo creo ha de existir código html sin cerrar. A los modals no hay por qué modificarle su z-index para que se muestren por encima del contenido. Puedes llegar a tener cuantos diálogos estimes, uno encima del otro que no afectarán.

Answer (score 0):

El modal si se esta abriendo, lo que veo un probelama es con el z-index. Prueba con un z-index poco superior, puede ser  50+. Agrega esta clase a contenedor principal, si no te funciona, comieza a mirar que propiedades de css (z-index) tiene cada div, y si no me dices, haber si te puedo ayudar.

```
.abrir-modal {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

Comment: Mejoró el aspecto pero igual sigue bloqueada la pantalla o sea no puedo interactuar con el programa cuando abro el modal

Comment: Toca mirar las propiedades css de los contenedores principales.  Estas usando angular para este fronted?

Comment: Html, js y php puro con bootstrap 4

Comment: Dejame ver el css de los div que estan antes de class="modal-content">

Comment: Estoy seguro que eso es por z-index, ya me ha pasado. Sin embargo agrega un nuevo  div que encierre toda el modal,  ese div le agregas la clase que te pase. Pero el z-index aumentalo a 1200. z-index:1200; Estuve viendo y 1050 es el que trae por defecto la clase de bootstrap. A mi me funciono porque lo saque a un nuevo contenedor como te digo.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste englobe el modal en un nuevo div que tenia la clase que me pasaste y le agregue en z-index: 1200 pero obtuve como resultado que la pantalla se me bloquea sin abrir el modal

Comment: Hay si toca es ver el css de los div principales, a la ciega es dificil opinar certeramente. Si quieres dejame ver las propiedades css haber si te puedo ayudar. Disculpas de mas :)

Comment: Ok gracias por la ayuda, puede ser también el tema que uso de bootstrap se me ocurre porque comenté en otros proyectos el modal abre sin problema y sin bloqueo de pantalla

Answer (score 0):

solo agreguen en el Div;

data-backdrop="false"

ejemplo:

1. Elemento de lista

   ```
          <div class="modal  " data-backdrop="false"  id="edit_<?php 
           echo $R['IDEstacion']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
           labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   ```

Comment: Saludos @jesus, tu respuesta quedaría más completa si agregas enlaces de documentación y la explicación de cómo tu propuesta soluciona el problema de OP. ;)